# Split linux bio to submit partial requests to different devices

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, kernel-module, device-driver

I am trying to do the following thing:

I have a kernel module that hooks into the make_request_fn function of a device-mapper device. In my kernel module I dispatch the bio to either the same device's make_request function, or to another device (that coincidentally happens to be the target device of the mapping, maybe this is important)

For certain bios whose sector range overlap an imaginary line, I need to split the bio request into two parts, first part to device 1, second part to device 2.

I tried to mimic what dm does for splitting bio, at high level overview this is what I did:

1. Call bio_clone() on original bio
2. Adjust bi_size for first clone to match size of first part
3. Replace bi_end_io of cloned bio with my own completion function so that I have control when cloned bio completes
4. submit cloned bio to first device with its make_request_fn(first_dev_queue, cloned_bio)
5. Wait until completion
6. Call bio_clone again on original bio, to create second clone
7. Call bio_advance() to adjust bi_sector, bi_size and bi_idx accordingly to the second part of the request. Also replace bi_end_io with my own completion function.
8. Manually fix clone's bi_bdev to correct device (device 2)
9. submit second bio clone to second device with its make_request_fn(second_dev_queue, cloned_bio)
10. Wait for completion
11. call bio_endio() on original IO

My problem is that the kernel thread hangs in __split_and_process_bio() at step 5) when I am waiting for the completion of the first cloned IO. Interestingly enough this seems to happen only on the second iteration, meaning I seem to have logs indicating that the first IO that I split this way succeeds, but then this happens on the second. This makes me think I don't properly complete something in the first iteration.

Any help in an explanation of the end to end process of splitting and returning back a bio to the caller would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: No I didn't. I am not working on this project anymore.